# Why does ORDER BY result change when joining the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Having these 2 tables

```
-- table moves
+-----+-----------+--------+---------+
| id  | reference |  side  | balance |
+-----+-----------+--------+---------+
|  1  |     1     | credit |   1000  |
|  2  |     2     | credit |   500   |
+-----+-----------+--------+---------+

-- table join_table
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|  1  |
|  2  |
+-----+
```

Now I want to select the moves from table #1 along with a calculated net balance column

I did that with this query

```
SELECT 
  moves.id,balance
  ,(@balance := @balance + (CASE side WHEN 'debit' THEN balance ELSE - balance END)) cum_balance
FROM 
   moves 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @balance := 0 blc)t
ORDER BY
     moves.id ASC
 ;
```

Which make the result that I want like

```
-- result #1
+-----+----------+---------------+
| id  | balance  |  cum_balance  |
+-----+----------+---------------+
|  1  |   1000   |    -1000      |
|  2  |   500    |    -1500      |
+-----+----------+---------------+
```

And when I want to calculate the net balance but when I order the table `DESC` , I just replace change the order

```
ORDER BY moves.id DESC
```

I get the expected result

```
-- result #2
+-----+----------+---------------+
| id  | balance  |  cum_balance  |
+-----+----------+---------------+
|  2  |   500    |    -500       |
|  1  |   1000   |    -1500      |
+-----+----------+---------------+
```

So far so good, the problems start when I join the table to other tables, like

```
SELECT 
  moves.id,balance
  ,(@balance := @balance + (CASE side WHEN 'debit' THEN balance ELSE - balance END)) cum_balance

FROM 
   moves 
   INNER JOIN join_table ON join_table.id = moves.reference -- remove this join to work
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @balance := 0 blc)t
ORDER BY
     moves.id DESC
 ;
```

**I get wrong result!!**

```
-- result #3
+-----+----------+---------------+
| id  | balance  |  cum_balance  |
+-----+----------+---------------+
|  2  |   500    |    -1500      |
|  1  |   1000   |    -1000      |
+-----+----------+---------------+
```

I was expecting to get the same result as result #2 , I don't know what is happening here. I hope I can understand **why the result changes when I join the table ?!**. and **how to get the expected result as result#2 while joining the table ?**

This is a SQLfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ea79/3) with the same schema mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure why, but if you display `@balance` on your query, you will see the variable doesnt match. That is because the calculation are process in the wrong order.  Also if you `ORDER BY id ASC` works ok.

To solve this you do the join and then the variable calculation.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ea79/16)**

```
SELECT *,
      (@balance := @balance + (CASE side 
                               WHEN 'debit' 
                               THEN balance ELSE - balance END)) cum_balance
FROM (
      SELECT 
        moves.id, 
        balance,
        side  
       FROM 
         moves 
         INNER JOIN join_table ON join_table.id = moves.reference
      ORDER BY
           moves.id DESC
      ) Q
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @balance := 0 blc)t
 ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Do you expect big difference in performance between the 2 queries when using this query on a big table ?

Comment: Well you will have to do a `FULL TABLE SCAN` so probably wont be lighting fast. But the best way is testing.

Comment: Interesting.  I've seen this problem with `GROUP BY` and variables.  I haven't specifically noticed it with `ORDER BY`.  But the same solution works -- materialize the table using a subquery and proceed.